# Control amount of UDP ports used by webRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, peerjs

I have simple webRTC app written with nodejs socket.io and peerJS. This app works great when there are no restrictions on the network, but yesterday I was informed by network admin that webRTC uses port range from 49152 to 65536 udp and thats to much.

How can I limit amount of ports that webRTC uses, the app allows only two streams so I don't need massive port ranges for connection.

This is my basic setup if needed I can post some server side code

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: '/peerjs',
  host: '/',
  port: '3000'
})
const peers = {}
let myVideoStream;
const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true;

Promise.resolve(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      aspectRatio: { ideal: 1.7777777778 },
      frameRate: { max: 24, }
    },
    audio: true
  })).then(stream => {
    console.log("server | camera | mic")
    myVideoStream = stream;

    myPeer.on('call', call => {
      call.answer(stream)
      const video = document.createElement('video')
      call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
      })
    })

    socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    })

  }).catch(() => {
    Promise.resolve(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        aspectRatio: { ideal: 1.7777777778 },
        frameRate: { max: 24, }
      },
      audio: false
    })).then(stream => {
      console.log("server | camera | no mic")
      myVideoStream = stream;

      myPeer.on('call', call => {
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
          addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
        })
      })

      socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
      })

    }).catch(() => {
      console.log("Server does not have camera or microphone available.")
    })
  })


socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
})


myPeer.on('open', id => {
  socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
  })
  call.on('close', () => {
    video.remove()
  })

  peers[userId] = call
}
```

Comment: I'd tell your network admin that if they care about reliability and security, they should get over it.